# How do I troubleshoot a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox

Code:

```
const elements = $(".container .element").first().nextAll().addBack();
```

Here's my HTML:

[image]

The code is supposed to grab the first element and all the content after it.  Depending on the HTML, this could return at a lot of different things, including nothing if I have a typo in my jQuery code. If the code that follows doesn't function correctly, how do I see what's inside `elements` for troubleshooting purposes?

I tried logging `elements.html()`, but that only printed the *contents* of the first element.

I tried using the Firefox debugger on `elements`, but the object is very complex, contains a lot of irrelevant troubleshooting information, and I couldn't figure out how to find what the jQuery object actually represents.

The only way I could figure out my code was correct was by logging `elements.text()`. That printed the text inside every element, and by doing that, I knew I had grabbed each one. It didn't tell me I grabbed the BR tags, but the documentation for nextAll said it would, so the gave me another faith it was doing what I wanted (I don't like relying on faith). The other problem with this solution is that it's highly contextual and won't work in all situations. There won't always be text in the HTML.

I'm out of ideas. **How do I see what's inside a jQuery object for troubleshooting purposes?**

Comment: try `console.log(elements);` - sorry if you've already tried this.

Comment: tl;dr: I already tried that. Actually I misspoke when I said I tried using the Firefox debugger: I did a `console.log( ) `instead. It's my understanding that it's effectively the same thing because I can expand what's logged just like I'd be able to in the debugger.

Comment: Try `console.log(elements.get())` That will log an array of all the DOM elements.

Comment: @Barmar I would accept this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
console.log(elements.get())
```

The jQuery `get()` method with no arguments returns the contained DOM elements as an array.